# Pointer to member function of instance instead of class

Tags: c++, c++11, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

I have the following class when I get a pointer to a member function according to some condition and then call the function.

```cpp
class Test
{
public:
    bool isChar(char ch) { return (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z'); }
    bool isNumeric(char ch) { return (ch >= '0' && ch <= '0'); }

    enum class TestType
    {
        Undefined,
        Char,
        Numeric,
        AnotherOne,
    };

    bool TestFor(TestType type, char ch)
    {
        typedef bool (Test::*fptr)(char);
        fptr f = nullptr;
        switch(type)
        {
            case TestType::Char:
                f = &Test::isChar;
                break;
            case TestType::Numeric:
                f = &Test::isNumeric;
                break;
            default: break;
        }

        if(f != nullptr)
        {
            return (this->*f)(ch);
        }

        return false;
    }
};
```

But actually I don't like the syntax. Is there a way to replace

```cpp
(this->*f)(ch)
```

with

```cpp
f(ch)
```

?

In my real code the function a big enough and it's not so clear what `(this->*f)` is. I'm looking for some `c++11` solution. I know about `std::function` and I will use it if if no solution will be found.

**Update**

The solution that I decided to use, if suddenly someone needs it:  (thanks for @StoryTeller - Unslander Monica)

```cpp
bool TestFor(TestType type, char ch)
{        
    bool(Test::* fptr)(char) = nullptr;
    switch(type)
    {
        case TestType::Char:
            fptr = &Test::isChar;
            break;
        case TestType::Numeric:
            fptr = &Test::isNumeric;
            break;
        default: break;
    }

    if(fptr != nullptr)
    {
        auto caller = std::mem_fn(fptr);
        return caller(this, ch);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: *"I don't like the syntax"* - Maybe so, but that syntax was designed *precisely* to allow you to do what you're doing. And regarding "it's not so clear what `(this->*f)` is." - it's evident to anyone that (a) knows C++, and (b) knows what pointer to member access is. The latter is important for proper context of what is *really* going on. Trying to *hide* that from someone that is perusing the code seems incredibly counter-productive. That said, you can `std::function`, or old(ish)-school and `std::bind` something together. It won't make the code any "better", but maybe you'll like the syntax.

Comment: In C++17, [`std::invoke`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke)`(f, this, ch)`?

Comment: BTW, `isChar` is wrong for EBCDIC. (range `a-z` is not guaranty to be contiguous).

Comment: yes, `std::invoke` could be a solution but my target board is a bit limited and supports `c++11` only.

Comment: @WhozCraig, you probably agree that `f(ch)` is much more understandable then `(this->*f)(ch)`?

Comment: I just noticed that your sample code functions don't access `this` but are evaluating the argument only. In this case, the other solution would be `static` member functions or even plain functions, and both might be assigned to and used with a "simple" function pointer.

Comment: @folibis I do *not* agree. The latter, `f(ch)`, obfuscates the fact that a member function of the current object is being indirectly invoked. You may not like the syntax, but it isn't just functional; it's communicative. That said, you don't lose that layer of communication by using `std::mem_fn` as in the selected answer. As such, that's a decent option.

Comment: I just saw that there already was an answer concerning this which is deleted now. It might be helpful to edit the question to point out that `static` member functions or plain functions are not an option for the real use case...

Comment: @Scheff'sCat, actually that can be solution too. In my real code I use a member variable inside these functions, but for sample code I've provided, yes this is one of the solutions.

Comment: `isChar` can be implemented correctly by simply calling `std::isalpha`. And `isNumeric` with `std::isdigit`. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @PeteBecker, sure, I know that, but your comment doesn't relate to the issue. The code is for example only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the syntax bothers you so much, you can always use [`std::mem_fn`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn) to generate a cheap one-time wrapper around a member function.

```
auto caller = std::mem_fn(f);
caller(this, ch);
```

Comment: Nice, solution. At least, more elegant. To my shame, I didn't know about `std::mem_fn`. I think this is what I'm going to use. Thank you very much!